# Flutter: How do I remove/disconnect OAuth provider like Google/Apple/Facebook from an account on my firebase application?

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-signin

How do I give the users of my firebase app the option to remove/disconnect an OAuth provider like Google/Apple/Facebook from their account?
I want to give this option to people who are registered in my app with the email&password provider (among other sign in provider(s)).

I have tried `GoogleSignIn().disconnect()`, but that didn't work, so idk what that method does.

---

See this screenshot from Duolingo as an example, where I have the option to remove the association between my duolingo account and my google account, without deleting my duolingo account (and then I can just log in with email and password later):

[image: See this screenshot from Duolingo as an example]

Comment: This might help : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect

Comment: Can you share your code on how you used `GoogleSignIn().disconnect()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I have finally found out how unlink (that's what they call it in the code & docs) an OAuth provider from an existing firebase account.

This is how I did it:

1. Use the method `FirebaseAuth.instance.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)` to know which auth providers your firebase account is linked to. This returns a `Future` that resolves to a `List<String>`, that looks like this for example: `[google.com, password]`, if your account is using both email&password and google for sign in.
   I use this information to correctly set the values of the sliders (as in the screenshot in the question).
2. Now have a look at this from the official firebase docs: [Unlink an auth provider from a user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/account-linking?hl=en&authuser=0#unlink_an_auth_provider_from_a_user_account). This is how to unlink an auth provider from a firebase account:

---

```
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.unlink('google.com');
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  switch (e.code) {
    case "no-such-provider":
      print("The user isn't linked to the provider or the provider"
          "doesn't exist.");
      break;
    default:
      print("Unkown error.");
  }
}
```

I have copied it into my code, and everything worked as expected, first try.